# Regex to split based on specific comma

Tags: java, regex

I have simple requirement. I have a small string and want to split based on **comma** but only that are **outside the parenthesis**.

Sample Input

```
SUM(Col1) OVER (PARTITION BY Col2, Col3) AS Col5,SUM(Col2) OVER (PARTITION BY Col2) AS Col4
```

Expected output:

```
SUM(Col1) OVER (PARTITION BY Col2, Col3) AS Col5
SUM(Col2) OVER (PARTITION BY Col2) AS Col4
```

Thanks

Comment: I presume the parentheses can be nested?  If so, I don't think this can be done with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through negative lookahead assertion. For this case negative lookahead assertion is the best option rather than positive lookahead.

```
,(?![^()]*\))
```

The above regex would match all the commas only if it's not followed by,

- `[^()]*` Any character but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times.
- `\)` A closing paranthesis.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zX7pH0/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
,(?=([^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/31

P.S this assumes there are no nested `(` or `)`.

---

Here is optimized regex that worked for me

```
,(?=[^)]+\()
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/nM6sH3/1)

Comment: Please can you add some explanation about this regex?

Comment: @Braj this check if a `,` is followed by multiple `(<something>)`.So if a `,` is inside `()` then it will not have multiple `()` ahead of it as there will be one `)` left.So that `,` will not match,

Comment: thanks for comments. I got your idea. This is what I need [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nM6sH3/1). `,(?=[^)]+\()`

Comment: @AvinashRaj that will not be the case. Column will not be inside parenthesis alone.